# WSS 3.0 / SharePoint Intermitant Workflow Firing

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, wss-3.0

I am experiencing some issues with workflows not starting on a Windows SharePoint Sevices 3.0 site at intermittent intervals.  The issue I have got is as follows…

I have several a SharePoint Designer Workflows attached to a forms library and I also have a few lists in SharePoint which also have several SharePoint Designer Workflows attached to them.  All the workflows I am experiencing problems with are all set the be able to be started manually and when an item is created in its respective list/library.  The problem I have got it that sometimes workflows are just not starting, however this is intermittent and has not logical reasoning to when they will or will not start… for example:

> When Form 1 I saved into its respective forms library (as it is an
>   InfoPath form) there are four workflows that should run, one workflow
>   always runs without any problems but the other three do not always
>   run… sometimes one or two of them run and the other one or two do not,
>   sometimes all three run and other times none of the three run.

I have this issue around different areas of my site and the workflows I am using are not of any complexity and use standard SharePoint Designer Workflow actions.  There are no time restraints around when these do/do not run and nothing on the server itself to indicate any errors with the SharePoint installation.

I have already ruled out the post SP2 issue with workflow starting under the ‘System Account’ as the forms are being saved by a combination of general users and the anonymous user (IUSR account) and (as I mentioned earlier) sometimes the workflows do start and sometimes they do not with no pattern, rhyme or reason.  As the issue with starting workflows under the ‘System Account’ is by design this would not cause any intermittent issues as I am experiencing.

The version of WSS 3.0 that I am running is SP2 (12.0.0.6421) and I am going to get this upgraded to the latest hotfix shortly as I am hoping this may help.

I have worked with WSS 3.0 for over 3.5 years now and never seen this issue… any information that is available will be very very very much appreciated as I am not 100% sure where else to go other than to Microsoft themselves…

Thank you to all in advance,
Luke